# Calling bash from R script in Ubuntu

Tags: r, bash

I have the following code that I want to run in R using `system` to call `bash`

```
> cat(test[[1]])
gpt /shared/Training/Bulk_with_R/AuxData/Graph.xml -Pinput1=/shared/Training/Bulk_with_R/Original/S2A_MSIL2A_20170604T112121_N0205_R037_T29TNE_20170604T112755.SAFE/MTD_MSIL2A.xml -Ptarget1=/shared/Training/Bulk_with_R/Processing/20170604.dim
```

If I run

```
system(test[[1]])
```

I get the following error:

```
> system(test[[1]])
sh: 1: gpt: not found
```

I guess it is because R is not using the correct shell. If I check the one used in termincal using `echo $0`, the output is `bash`

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like the gpt is not on the $PATH. Please try with absolute path to the command.

Comment: Does the command execute when you run it in the terminal?

Comment: @MikeVolokhov, totally right, that was my fault. Any idea on how to set gpt as $PATH so that I do not have to use the absolute path?

Comment: Cross site good read about how to set up environment variables : https://askubuntu.com/questions/866161/setting-path-variable-in-etc-environment-vs-profile

Comment: Well, this might be either R or the shell invoked through the system() call which misses path to the gpt. First, please ensure R has the right $PATH: Sys.getenv("PATH")  If there is directory where the gpt resides, please check shell (bash in your case) startup files - it may miss proper PATH declaration. Please note, if both R PATH and the shell PATH looks good to you, referencing the gpt by its absolute path might be the best option.